# Trying to discern if a Moto G is fake

Tags: motorola-moto-g

A Moto G arrived today from China and I'm not sure if it's real or not, the icons on the box don't have particularly smooth edges (which would be the case if it were a scan)

Could someone take a screenshot of their "About phone" (in settings) particularly the kernel version and the Android version, this phone has some weird one.

Do the power/volume  buttons on the side feel very sharp?

Is the viewing angle of the screen really poor and the pixels quite large?

I will post some pictures

Here's the edge
[image]

Comment: There is an app called CPU Z (I can't past the link for some reason) that will give you all the details of your hardware, post the results here and we'll know. Also the about device screen should be telling, as posted in an answer below. A friend's moto g is nice and sharp and surprisingly fluid and fast. It doesn't sound good to be honest.

Comment: @RossC that'd mean getting a google account working and all that on it, that's why I have not.

Comment: Ah, Chinese phones don't have any google services on them. Sorry about that, completely forgot. You could try the Amazon App Store and go about it that way. To be honest it doesn't sound good to me, it should be smooth hardware wise and have a nice crisp screen. It should be a 720p screen (That's 720x1280 pixels on a small screen! While not quite a Note 4 it's still great). It's not full HD but it would be nice at sharp at 4.5" for sure. It's a very nice, fast, fluid phone IMHO. That is not what you're describing here sadly.

Comment: @RossC it has Chrome, some moto stuff and the play store I think, that's the thing, it's just got some weird things like the picture above and the screen's quality

Answer (score 2):

This is the About screen of my Moto G. As far as I can tell the buttons don't feel sharp.

[image]

As proposes in a comment, you can try [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=pt_BR) and it will show the phone's information (CPU, model, etc...).

Comment: The kernel version and name (falcon_umtsds) is similar across both, you see the picture I posted, is yours like that? Alec

Comment: Thanks for the reply BTW, the about phone screen is similar on this device, this is easily faked of course, if yours was totally different then we'd know, as they are the same it's an inconclusive test, thanks for taking the time and all.

Comment: please take a quick look at the picture in my question!